# Need to convert string to format usable by .hex() or other hex conversion method

Tags: python

I am reading hex data from a .csv file that has multiple rows (example format:  FFFDF3FFFBF2FFFAF210FFF0) using the following code:

```
with open('c:\\temp\\results.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
    line_count = 0
    file = open('c:\\temp\\sent.csv', 'w')
    for row in csv_reader:
        hex_string = f'{row[0]}'
        bytes_object = bytes.fromhex(hex_string)
        file.write(str(bytes_object) + '\n')
        line_count += 1
    file.close()
```

The output file contains mutliple rows that are converted to this format (sorry new to python so not sure if this is a bytearray or what it is actually called): b'\xff\xfd\xf3\xff\xfb\xf2\xff\xfa\xf2\x10\xff\xf0'

I am trying to convert back from this format to the orginal format reading the rows of the newly created .csv file (need to edit readable ascii in the file and covert back for use in another program).

```
file = open('c:\\temp\\sent.csv', 'r')
  for row in file:
      byte_string = row
    # hex_object = byte_string.hex()
     #THIS works if I enter the byte array in directly, but not if reading 
     #from file hex_object = byte_string.hex()
      hex_object = b'\xff\xfd\x03\xff\xfb\x03\xff\xfd\x01\xff\xfb\x17\xff\xfa\xff\xf0\xff\xfd\x00\xff\xfb\x00'.hex() 
      print(hex_object)
     #print(byte_string)
    # writer.writerow(hex_object)
```

Is there a way to get this to work?  I have tried several encoding methods, but since the data is already in the proper format I really just need to get it in a readable type for the .hex() method.  I am using the latest version of Python 3.8.1`enter code here`

Comment: If you need the unconverted hex string then why bother converting it to bytes first? Just treat it as any other string.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing a textual representation of your bytes object and then trying to read it back without conversion to/from binary. Instead you are better off opening the output file in binary format like this:

```
file = open('c:\\temp\\sent.csv', 'wb')
```

and write the bytes to file:

```
bytes_object = bytes.fromhex(hex_string)
file.write(bytes_object)
```

(no need for newline character).

Then to do the opposite open in binary format:

```
with open('c:\\temp\\sent.csv', "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
    s = data.hex()
    print(s)
```

Here `data` is a bytes object and it has the `hex()` function you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that allowed me to do the convert back and forth; however, when converting back to hex there is a lot of extra data that wasn't part of the source.  I need to do a line by line conversion to read and edit and then convert it back line by line to combine it with another data file into a new .csv that matches the two data source row by row

Comment: @SteveB You probably need to add a separator in `hex_string` for each line. Then when reading back split on that separator because a binary file is just a series of bytes.